# Finding integer number from a set of strings

Tags: python-3.x

Hi I wanted to solve a problem which is as follows:-
If I/P is "OZONETOWER" O/P is 012 i.e. 0's string (ZERO) is compared to the input string and when found, it appears in the output and so on for 1 and 2.
Providing the set of inputs and outputs for refrence:-

```
I/P:                               O/P:
WEIGHFOXTOURIST                    2468
OURNEONFOE                         114
ETHER                               3
```

I already tried this but this doesn't seem to give the results for all cases.

```
def puzzle(dic_number,string,key):
    dic_values=0    
    length=len(dic_number)
    for i in dic_number:
        if i in string:
            dic_values+=1
    if dic_values ==length:
        print(key)


dic1={0:"ZERO",1:"ONE",2:"TWO",3:"THREE",4:"FOUR",5:"FIVE",6:"SIX",7:"SEVEN",8:"EIGHT",9:"NINE"}
string=input("Enter number")

for i,j in enumerate(dic1.values()):
    puzzle(j,string,i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def puzzle(s):
    supper = s.upper()
    ret = []
    for n, chrs in numbers.items():
        while True:
            if all(c in supper for c in chrs):
                for c in chrs:
                    supper = supper.replace(c, '', 1)
                ret.append(n)
            else:
                break
    return ret
```

Comment: Try to avoid code only answer and provide some explanation in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to implement this:

```
numbers = {
    0: "ZERO",
    1: "ONE",
    2: "TWO",
    3: "THREE",
    4: "FOUR",
    5: "FIVE",
    6: "SIX",
    7: "SEVEN",
    8: "EIGHT",
    9: "NINE",
}


def puzzle(s):
    supper = s.upper()
    ret = []
    for n, chrs in numbers.items():
        if all(c in supper for c in chrs):
            ret.append(n)
    return ret


s = input("enter string ")

numbers_found = puzzle(s)
print('numbers found', numbers_found)
```

**Output:**

```
enter string WEIGHFOXTOURIST
numbers found [2, 3, 4, 6, 8]
enter string OURNEONFOE
numbers found [1, 4]
enter string ETHER
numbers found [3]
enter string OZONETOWER
numbers found [0, 1, 2]
```

**Note**

With this implementation

- you get an additional result of `3` for the input `WEIGHFOXTOURIST`
- you get `1, 4` instead of `1, 1, 4` for the input `OURNEONFOE`

---

**EDIT**

To get repeated matches the puzzle function has to "consume" characters already used:

```
def puzzle(s):
    supper = s.upper()
    ret = []
    for n, chrs in numbers.items():
        while True:
            if all(c in supper for c in chrs):
                for c in chrs:
                    supper = supper.replace(c, '', 1)
                ret.append(n)
            else:
                break
    return ret
```

**Output:**

```
enter string WEIGHFOXTOURIST
numbers found [2, 3, 6]
enter string OURNEONFOE
numbers found [1, 1, 4]
enter string ETHER
numbers found [3]
enter string OZONETOWER
numbers found [0, 1, 2]
```

**Note**

With this implementation

- you do not get a result of `8` for the input `WEIGHFOXTOURIST`

---

**Explanation:**

In this puzzle it is considered a "match" when all the letters of a number are found in the input string.

To do that we check each character one by one by creating a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) over the characters of the string:

```
>>> chrs = 'FOUR'
>>> [c for c in chrs]
['F', 'O', 'U', 'R']
```

For each of the characters we use [`in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations) to check if it is found in the uppercased input string:

```
>>> chrs = 'FOUR'
>>> supper = 'OURNEONFOE'
>>> [c in supper for c in chrs]
[True, True, True, True]
```

If a character is not found it will produce a `False` at the corresponding position:

```
>>> chrs = 'FOUR'
>>> supper = 'OXRNEONFOE'
>>> [c in supper for c in chrs]
[True, True, False, True]
```

Then with [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) we check if all items of the list are `True`

```
>>> chrs = 'FOUR'
>>> supper = 'OURNEONFOE'
>>> all([c in supper for c in chrs])
True
>>> supper = 'OXRNEONFOE'
>>> all([c in supper for c in chrs])
False
```

And since [`PEP 289`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) we can use the generator expression directly in `all`

```
>>> chrs = 'FOUR'
>>> supper = 'OURNEONFOE'
>>> all(c in supper for c in chrs)
True
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, works pretty good.. Can you explain what this line does exactly:-
```
if all(c in supper for c in chrs):

Comment: @shubham I added an explanation to my answer